# Unquote symbol in lambda expression?

Tags: variables, emacs, elisp, backquote

In an anonymous function such as

```
(lambda () x)
```

how can I replace the symbol `x` with its value in the current scope?

The only thing I can think of is

```
(eval `(lambda () ,x))
```

but I wonder if there's another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `eval`.  Just `` `(lambda () ,x) ``.

That returns the *list* `(lambda () VAL-X)`, where `VAL-X` is the value of variable `x`.  And a lambda list is interpreted by Emacs as a function.

Comment: This will happily burp if `x` has a value such as `(1 2)`.

Comment: @Stefan: I tried to stay as close to the OP as possible. And this returns `(lambda () (1 2))` - no burp. If you mean that *that* function burps when invoked, that's a different problem (and it applies to the OP too). If `x` is likely to be something that cannot be evaluated without error then `',x` is usually appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to add

```
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
```

at the beginning of your file.  Once you've done that, writing `(lambda () x)` is all it takes, since Emacs will then take care of replacing that `x` with the value from the scope surrounding that lambda (i.e. will create a proper closure).

Comment: The problem is it's not always possible to do that. For instance, imagine you're extending a library that doesn't use lexical binding.

Comment: It's always possible, and usually easy, to convert a file to `lexical-binding`.